# Good/Correct way to write this due to Haskell operator precedence?

Tags: haskell, operators

This code works:

```
40 * sum [1..10]
```

This code does not:

```
40 * sum $ map id [1..10]
```

I now understand it to be because this is grouped into `(40 * sum) (map id [1..10])` due to operator precedence instead of what I think it should be, which is `(40 *) (sum (map id [1..10]))`.

Is there a proper way to write this in Haskell other than using parentheses?

Comment: just use parens: `40 * (sum $ map id [1..10])`

Comment: You could make a new operator that is like `$` but with a higher fixity than `*`. I *really* wouldn't suggest this though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know of no way to write this expression properly without using parentheses, but I would prefer to see something more like one of the following

```
(40 *) $ sum $ map id [1..10]

40 * (sum $ map id [1..10])

(*) 40 $ sum $ map id [1..10]

(40 *) . sum . map id $ [1..10]
```

Instead of

```
(40 *) (sum (map id [1..10]))
```

You could get rid of the parens in this particular expression if you aliased `(*)` to a function rather than an operator:

```
mult :: Num a => a -> a -> a
mult = (*)

expr :: Int
expr = mult 40 $ sum $ map id [1..10]
```

However, I wouldn't worry too much about having some parentheses, in this case it isn't a huge deal to have them.  Introducing a new name just to circumvent a small amount of normal syntax would just make your code more difficult to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

The answer which is closer to your original expression, `40 * sum $ map id [1..10]`, is to consider that `(*)` is just the name of a function, so that parenthesis are just part of the name, not grouping symbols, and rewriting your expression as:

```
(*) 40 . sum $ map id [1..10]
```

This way also avoids problems with precedence, which affects only to infix form of binary functions (operators).

Functional programming encourage the use of composition versus application, so a more "proper" way, as you are asking for, would be this slight variation:

```
(*) 40 . sum . map id $ [1..10]
```